# Number Format Exception Errors

Tags: java, exception

I get this error whenever I run my program:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9999997560"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
    at jsobcpuburnerpd3.Main.main(Main.java:22)
    Java Result: 1
```

The program has two do-while loops that are nearly identical, and the first works perfectly. I only have problems with the second one.

```
BigDecimal lower = new BigDecimal("1000001520");
BigDecimal upper = new BigDecimal("9999997560");
int var = 2520;

String strL = lower.toString();
Integer intL = Integer.valueOf(strL);

String strU = upper.toString();
Integer intU = Integer.valueOf(strU);
```

Both numbers have the same amount of digits, and are converted to Integer the same way. Both are handled nearly the same way in the loops.

```
intL = intL + var;

intU = intU - var;
```

I have also attempted this without converting from BigDecimal to String, and inputting the number directly to String, but still got the same error.

**EDIT** I am using BigDecimal because it's a part of what my teacher wanted us to use in our work. I know it's not needed.

Comment: Why are you starting with a `BigDecimal`, to convert it to a `String` (that you already have since you contrusted the `BigDecimal` with it) only to make an `Integer` out of that?!

Comment: Your first mistake was making the assumption that _Both numbers have the same amount of digits_ is related to the data types in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you will get a number format exception because the maximum value that can be store in an Integer is 2,147,483,647 which is less than 9,999,997,560.

On the other hand 1,000,001,520 is less than 2,147,483,647 which is why that works fine.

(Edit Based on Tunaki's suggestion) FYI - Moreover you really don't have to use a BigDecimal because it seems that the only reason you need it is to convert it to an Integer. So it is not required.

Also an Integer is not required because you don't seem to be requiring a reference type and hence the primitive type int should be apt. Moreover in your for loop you are adding and subtracting values from Integer which will lead to unnecessary boxing and unboxing and will be very inefficient. So use the primitive type int which would be better.

Comment: This is true enough, but it won't solve the clear [XY situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here: see my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604954/number-format-exception-errors#comment60806898_36604954

Comment: Yes that is correct. He didn't have to use an Integer at all. And moreover looks like he is using this Integer in a for-loop which will lead to unnecessary unboxing and boxing when he increments it. He might as well have begun with an int and things would have worked just fine.

But anyway the question is related to why he is getting a numberFormatException and I sought to address that.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me find a solution, and now my code works. I ended up getting rid of String strU and used a BigInteger instead of BigDecimal, and put it into a long. But, now my code executes properly with all of the required stuff.

Answer (score -2):

Convert the BigInteger to Integer using intValue() Method

```
BigDecimal lower = new BigDecimal("1000001520");
BigDecimal upper = new BigDecimal("9999997560");

Integer intBL = lower.intValue();
Integer intBU = upper.intValue();
```

Comment: From the docs: *if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned.* How do you know the OP wants that?